# React Native - Cache Images

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-persist

**Problem**

I want to store the images the app downloaded from the server, something similar to Instagram or Facebook.

I viewed redux persist, but I don't know is the best option to do this.

Some advices to do this, I have around 30 business inside the app and every business has 5 images, around 150 images I have to store in the app. Each image weighs around 50k.

**Versions**

- React Native 0.59.8
- Redux 4.0.4
- Redux Persist 5.10.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your app is on iOS only then you can use the following example as seen in docs [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images#cache-control-ios-only).

```
<Image
  source={{
    uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/logo-og.png',
    cache: 'only-if-cached',
  }}
  style={{width: 400, height: 400}}
/>
```

and maybe you can use `cache: 'force-cache'` .

And if your app is on multiple platforms then a better alternative would be a package called [react-native-cached-image](https://github.com/kfiroo/react-native-cached-image). Try the docs it's easy to implement this.

Comment: Thank you, it is very helpfull. I am building both apps, Android and iOS.

Comment: I don't know why, but in my emulator, images are cached by default with Image component. Android emulator.

Comment: [react-native-cached-image](https://github.com/kfiroo/react-native-cached-image) is pretty outdated and abandoned, even for the time this answer was posted. Its last commit was at 24 Oct 2017.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for https://github.com/xerdnu/react-native-blasted-image